# Is there a way of finding compound interest in java with inputs using JOptionPane?

Tags: java, joptionpane

I've tried with the following inputs:

> principal= 1000, rate=4, timesapplied=2(half-yearly), elapsedyears=2

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class CICalc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double principal;
        Double rate;
        Double timesapplied;
        Double elapsedyears;

        principal= Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the principal amount"));
        rate=Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the Rate of Interest"));
        timesapplied=Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of times the principal is compounded"));
        elapsedyears=Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the amount of time(In years and if in months, write them in this format- month/12) the principal is being invested for"));

        BigDecimal CI;
        BigDecimal inf;
        inf= BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.pow(rate+(1/timesapplied*100),elapsedyears*timesapplied));

        CI= (BigDecimal.valueOf(principal)).multiply(inf);
        BigDecimal P= CI.subtract(BigDecimal.valueOf(principal));

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The Compound Interest for "+elapsedyears+" years is "+CI+"$ and the the interest gained is "+P+"$");

    }
}
```

Can someone please point out the mistakes and help me out? Actually, I had made this using only `Double` but the problem was that the result had way too many decimal points. So I had to use `BigDecimal`.

Comment: This is actually more of a mathematical/financial type of question about calculation of compound interest. It does not fall under programming. I have therefore taken off my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Actually, I had made this using only Double but the problem was that
>   the result had way too many decimal points. So I had to use
>   BigDecimal.

Use [BigDecimal setScale​(int newScale, RoundingMode roundingMode)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale(int,java.math.RoundingMode)) to round the result up to the required number of decimal places.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double principal = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the principal amount"));
        double rate = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the Rate of Interest"));
        double timesapplied = Double
                .parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of times the principal is compounded"));
        double elapsedyears = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of years"));

        double base = 1.0 + rate / (timesapplied * 100.0);
        double exponent = elapsedyears * timesapplied;

        double inf = Math.pow(base, exponent);
        double CI = principal * inf;
        double P = CI - principal;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "The Compound Interest for " + BigDecimal.valueOf(elapsedyears).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
                        + " years is " + BigDecimal.valueOf(CI).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
                        + "$ and the the interest gained is " + BigDecimal.valueOf(P).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
                        + "$");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! That is kind of what I figured out-

Comment: `BigDecimal CI;
BigDecimal inf;
inf= BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.pow(1+(r/(n*100)),t*n));
CI=p.multiply(inf).setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
BigDecimal P= CI.subtract(p).setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The Compound Interest for "+t+" years is $"+CI+" and the the interest gained per year is $" +P.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(2.0)) +". In year "+t+", it is $"+P);
}
}`

Answer (score 0):

Your formula for compound interest was wrong.  The [formula](https://www.google.com/search?q=compound%20interest%20formula&oq=compound%20interest%20formula&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.9959j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is

```
final amount = initial amount times
    1 + interest rate / number of times interest applied
    raised to the power of number of times interest applied
    times number of time periods elapsed
```

The interest rate, which is normally defined as a percentage per year has to be converted to a number per time period by dividing by 100 and dividing by the number of time periods in a year.

As far as your code, I made a method to get the input values.

I also broke up the compound interest calculation so I could verify the results of each part of the calculation.

Here's the revised code.

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CICalc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

        double principal = getValue("Enter the principal amount");
        double rate = getValue("Enter the yearly interest rate");
        double timesapplied = getValue("Enter the number of times "
                + "the principal is compounded per year");
        double elapsedmonths = getValue("Enter the amount of time "
                + "in months the principal is invested");

        double temp1 = 1.0d + rate * 0.01d / timesapplied;
        double temp2 = timesapplied * elapsedmonths / 12d;
        double finalAmount = principal * Math.pow(temp1, temp2);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "The total amount returned after " +
                elapsedmonths +
                " months is " + nf.format(finalAmount) +
                " and the the interest gained is " +
                nf.format(finalAmount - principal));
    }

    private static double getValue(String prompt) {
        String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(prompt);
        return Double.parseDouble(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting! Although I figured it out today morning (it was something of a _eureka_ moment actually), those are definitely better arranged and a bit too confusing for me as I've just started. I'll try and understand it first, then implement some of the more efficient parts of the code you've given.